# How can I set cookies in a browser from a Rails API app hosted in Heroku running the frontend in a React app hosted in Netlify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, session-cookies, netlify, csrf-token

I built an API with Rails *--api --db:postgres* flags. I built the frontend in another app using React *create app*.

- Rails 6.1.4.1, Ruby 3.0.2p107
- The Rails app is deployed in Heroku
- The React app, in Netlify
- I'm using session cookies to store the user id, and the CSRF Token for additional security (mainly for learning purposes)

Both cookies are set properly and as expected in my local environment, by running the rails server in port **localhost:3001** and react in port **localhost:3000**.

However, after deploying Rails in herokuapp.com and React in netlify.app, although the browser receives the cookies in the response, it doesn't set them.

This is what I see in the browser:

[Cookies Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KODd.png)

My Cors.rb file is set properly to allow my the netlify domain to connect to the server, like so **my-domain.netlify.app** and **https://my-domain.netlify.app**.

When setting the cookies I have tried every imaginable possible combination of settings, but nothing seems to work. At the moment it looks something like this:

```
def set_csrf_cookie
    cookies['CSRF-TOKEN'] = {
      value: form_authenticity_token,
      domain: my-app.herokuapp.com,
      same_site: :None,
      secure: true
    }
end
```

In my cors.rb file I have this code on the first line:

```
Rails.application.config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check = false
```

My application.rb file has this config:

```
config.api_only = true
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

My application controller looks something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :set_csrf_cookie

  include ActionController::Cookies
  include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  include Response
  include ExceptionHandler

  def cookie
    'ok'
  end

  private

  def set_csrf_cookie
    cookies['CSRF-TOKEN'] = {
      value: form_authenticity_token,
      domain: 'my-app.herokuapp.com',
      same_site: :None,
      secure: true
    }
  end
end
```

I set the cookies by making an API call from my **App.js** component. The call is made to the *path '/'*, which is routed to *application#cookie*, which you can see in the application controller code above.

I know I am able to connect with the API because some endpoints that don't require the CSRF Token, are working properly.

I have a feeling that my issue has something to do with the app being hosted in 2 different domains. I also think that it might be a front-end issue, not a back-end issue.

Help from anyone who has successfully done this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After much research and a lot of tests, I discovered that the main reason why my cookies were not working is because of the way browsers handle third-party cookies nowadays.
It turns out that Safari and Chrome block them by default. I also missed the fact that cross-site cookies don't actually exist.

I wrote an article explaining how I solved the issue: https://medium.com/@ArturoAlvarezV/use-session-cookies-to-authenticate-a-user-with-a-rails-api-backend-hosted-in-heroku-on-one-domain-f702ddf8c07

Basically, my solution was very simple, remove cross-site-tracking protection from the browsers, using Ruby on Rails gem called 'rails_same_site_cookie', and add this line to my production.rb file:

```
config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :None
```

This did the trick for me. This line turned all cookies in rails to `SameSite:None` and `Secure:true` by default, including Rail's built-in session cookie.

My developer tools don't show the cookies in my cookies panel, but now they are set and sent with my credentials every time I make a request to the API.

Comment: I would suggest you to manage the session using access tokens or something similar like JWT, not relaying on cookies for api calls

Comment: Yes, thanks. During this time I was under the impression that cookies would be safer than using tokens, but this may be true in the case where your API and Client are hosted within the same domain name.